# C++ elegant way to combine switch with if and variable assignment

Tags: c++, switch-statement

My code looks like this

```
enum possible_cases; //assigned somewhere
bool decision; //assigned somewhere

//basically the default action for my possible_cases
int value = 10;
do_something(value);

switch (possible_cases)
{
    case 0:
        //assume covered by do_something(value)
        break;
    case 1:
        if ( decision )
        {
            value = get_other_value();
            do_something(value);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        value = get_other_value(); //will return same value as in case 1
        do_something(value);
        break;
}
```

As you see

1. it has to run `do_something()` with one specific value
2. it might have to run `do_something()` with other values **additionally**, and the list of cases might grow, to a point, where having bools is impractical

but overall I am not happy as it is kinda redundant and I think there is a way to do it better.

I would like to stay with enum of cases

Edit:

It seems not clear where the problem is:

I see the call of the same function in 3 places, while I assume I could reduce it to 2  as I know I need to run it only 2 times at max.
It is really more the aesthetic aspect

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of `do_something` being a method on a proxy object that returns a reference to itself. That allows you to write `do_something(value).do_something(some_other_value)` and so on, perhaps even an overload that's a no-op, so `do_something(nothing)` does nothing except return a reference to the proxy object.

Comment: Not clear to me what the issue is, really. Is `do_something` related to the enum class? `get_other_value()` does not seem to depend on anything.

Comment: Too vague to answer.

Comment: In this case, you can do `if(possible_cases == 2 || possible_cases == 1 && decision) //...`. But in general, it's too vague to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redundant part in your code is do_something(value)
So I would suggest you to separate that part of the code

```
enum possible_cases; //assigned somewhere
bool decision; //assigned somewhere

//basically the default action for my possible_cases
int value = 10;

switch (possible_cases)
{
    case 1:
        if ( decision )
            value = get_other_value();
        break;
    case 2:
        value = get_other_value(); //will return same value as in case 1
        break;
}
do_something(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding extra layer you might do:

```
std::optional<int>
get_additionnal_value(Epossible_cases possible_cases, bool decision)
{
    //basically the default action for my possible_cases
    const int value = 10;
    
    switch (possible_cases)
    {
    default:
    case 0: return std::nullopt;
#if 1
    case 1: return decision ? get_other_value() : value;
#else
    case 1: if (!decision) return value;
            [[fallthrough]];
#endif
    case 2: return get_other_value(); //will return same value as in case 1
    }
}
```

and then

```
do_something(10);
if (auto opt_value = get_additionnal_value(possible_cases, decision)) {
    do_something(opt_value);
}
```